# JQuery UI: Can't get target element of event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, event-handling

I use slickgrid. One column (the first one) contains a link. Now when hovering over the link (mouseenter in jquery) a jquery ui dialog is shown containing some of the data that would be visible when clicking on the link. Often this will prevent the user from having to click on the link.

Because users can add rows to the grid dynamically I use the on() to bind the events

```
$("#grid").on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        //here I get the correct element but have to store it in global var
        myNumber = $(this).text(); 
        $( "#dialog-char" ).dialog("open");
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $( "#dialog-char" ).dialog( "close" );
    }
},
    ".char-link"
);
```

I want to pass myNumber to the dialog open function:

```
$( "#dialog-char" ).dialog({
    resizable: true,
    width: 750,
    autoOpen: false,
    open: function( event, ui ) {
        loadChar(myNumber);
    }
});
```

Like this it works but again I need the global variable. How can I access the link within the open() function? `event.target` isn't the link, it's the div containing the grid. the other target properties all return undefined.

Is is this possible at all?

Comment: please create a fiddle of code

Comment: where's the function `loadChar(myNumber);` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it doesn't look like there's a straight forward way. If you want to avoid a global variable, you could bind the info regarding hovered link to `#dialog-char` before opening it, using `data()` method as follows:

```
$("#grid").on({
  mouseenter: function () {
    $( "#dialog-char" ).data('myNumber',$(this).text()); 
    $( "#dialog-char" ).dialog("open");
  },
  mouseleave: function () {
    $( "#dialog-char" ).dialog( "close" );
  }
},
".char-link"
);

$( "#dialog-char" ).dialog({
 resizable: true,
 width: 750,
 autoOpen: false,
 open: function( event, ui ) {
    myNumber= $(this).data('myNumber');
 }
});
```